# Gráficos en tiempo real con Matplotlib y Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, matplotlib, python-3.7

Estoy codificando una aplicación que debe graficar en tiempo real los datos de 3 sensores. Por el momento estoy "simulando", por decirlo de alguna manera, los datos de los sensores con tres generadores de python de la siguiente forma:

```
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


data = collections.deque([0]*100, maxlen=100)
data2 = collections.deque([0]*100, maxlen=100)
data3 = collections.deque([0]*100, maxlen=100)

def data_gen():
    for k in range(100):
        t=k/100
        yield 0.5*np.sin(40*t)*np.exp(-2*t)

def data_gen2():
    for k in range(100):
        t=k/100
        yield 0.5*np.sin(60*t)

def data_gen3():
    for k in range(100):
        t=k/100
        yield 0.5*np.cos(60*t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_title('Signal')
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
lines = ax.plot([], [])[0]
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = plt.axes()
ax2.set_title('Signal2')
ax2.set_xlabel("Time")
ax2.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax2.set_xlim(0,100)
ax2.set_ylim(-1,1)
lines2 = ax2.plot([], [])[0]
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = plt.axes()
ax3.set_title('Signal3')
ax3.set_xlabel("Time")
ax3.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax3.set_xlim(0,100)
ax3.set_ylim(-1,1)
lines3 = ax3.plot([], [])[0]

def animate(values):
    value=values
    data.append(value)
    lines.set_data(range(0,100),data)
    return lines

def animate2(values):
    value=values
    data2.append(value)
    lines2.set_data(range(0,100),data2)
    return lines2

def animate3(values):
    value=values
    data3.append(value)
    lines3.set_data(range(0,100),data3)
    return lines3


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, data_gen, interval=5)
anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate2, data_gen2, interval=5)
anim3 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig3, animate3, data_gen3, interval=5)
plt.show()
```

Hasta este momento no tengo mayores dificultades, ya que puedo visualizar en tiempo real las tres señales:

[image: Gráficos]

La principal duda es como incorporar los gráficos en tiempo real en una interfaz gráfica con Tkinter, por ejemplo algo sencillo como lo siguiente:

[image: Interfaz]

Donde al presionar el botón start comience a graficar y al presionar stop se termine de graficar en los tres gráficos simultáneamente.

He hecho varias pruebas pero sin ningún resultado. Lo más probable es que la forma en la que estoy llevando el código adelante no sea la mejor, ya que a medida que agrego más gráficos mas lento se vuelve el graficado en tiempo real. Por lo tanto cualquier sugerencia o corrección en bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib dispone de varios backends para embeber figuras en distintos frameworks gráficos, incluido Tkinter. No hay ningún problema con la animación ni hay que lidiar con concurrencia para evitar bloqueos del mainloop ni nada.

Te dejo un ejemplo completo basado en tu código a modo de ejemplo:

```
import collections
import tkinter as tk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import numpy as np



class VentanaSeñales(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        plt.style.use('dark_background')
        self.frame_graficas = tk.Frame(self, bg="#6E6E6E")
        self._figure_1, self._ax1 = plt.subplots()
        self._figure_1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(
            self._figure_1, master=self.frame_graficas
            )
        self._figure_2, self._ax2 = plt.subplots()
        self._figure_2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(
            self._figure_2, master=self.frame_graficas
            )
        self._figure_3, self._ax3 = plt.subplots()
        self._figure_3_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(
            self._figure_3, master=self.frame_graficas
            )

        self.frame_graficas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="fig")
        self.frame_graficas.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="fig")
        self.frame_graficas.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform="fig")

        self._figure_1_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(
            row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 30), pady=(30, 30),
            sticky="nsew"
            )
        self._figure_2_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(
            row=0, column=1, padx=(10, 30), pady=(30, 30),
            sticky="nsew"
            )
        self._figure_3_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(
            row=0, column=2, padx=(10, 30), pady=(30, 30),
            sticky="nsew"
            )


        self.frame_botones = tk.Frame(self, bg="#151515")
        self.btn_iniciar = tk.Button(
            self.frame_botones, bg="#7401DF", fg="#FFBF00",
            activebackground="#8258FA", font=('Courier', 16),
            text="Iniciar", command=self.iniciar_animación
            )
        self.btn_pausar = tk.Button(
            self.frame_botones, bg="#7401DF", fg="#FFBF00",
            activebackground="#8258FA", font=('Courier', 16),
            text="  Pausa  ", command=self.pausar_animación, state=tk.DISABLED
            )
        self.btn_iniciar.pack(
            side="left", padx=(100, 100), pady=(100, 100),
            fill="y", expand=True
            )
        self.btn_pausar.pack(
            side="left", padx=(100, 100), pady=(100, 100),
            fill="y", expand=True
            )

        self._anim1 = None
        self._anim2 = None
        self._anim3 = None

        self.frame_graficas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frame_botones.pack(fill="x")
        self._init_axes()

    def _init_axes(self):

        self._ax1.set_title('Signal')
        self._ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
        self._ax1.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self._ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)
        self._ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        self._ax2.set_title('Signal2')
        self._ax2.set_xlabel("Time")
        self._ax2.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self._ax2.set_xlim(0, 100)
        self._ax2.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        self._ax3.set_title('Signal3')
        self._ax3.set_xlabel("Time")
        self._ax3.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
        self._ax3.set_xlim(0, 100)
        self._ax3.set_ylim(-1, 1)


    def iniciar_animación(self):

        def animate(values):
            value=values
            data.append(value)
            lines.set_data(range(0, 100), data)
            return lines

        def animate2(values):
            value=values
            data2.append(value)
            lines2.set_data(range(0, 100), data2)
            return lines2

        def animate3(values):
            value=values
            data3.append(value)
            lines3.set_data(range(0, 100), data3)
            return lines3

        def data_gen():
            for k in range(100):
                t = k / 100
                yield 0.5 * np.sin(40 * t) * np.exp(-2 * t)

        def data_gen2():
            for k in range(100):
                t = k / 100
                yield 0.5 * np.sin(60 * t)

        def data_gen3():
            for k in range(100):
                t = k / 100
                yield 0.5 * np.cos(60 * t)

        if self._anim1 is None:
            lines = self._ax1.plot([], [], color='#80FF00')[0]
            lines2 = self._ax2.plot([], [], color='#80FF00')[0]
            lines3 = self._ax3.plot([], [], color='#80FF00')[0]

            data = collections.deque([0] * 100, maxlen=100)
            data2 = collections.deque([0] * 100, maxlen=100)
            data3 = collections.deque([0] * 100, maxlen=100)

            self._anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(
                self._figure_1, animate, data_gen, interval=5
                )
            self._anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(
                self._figure_2, animate2, data_gen2, interval=5
                )
            self._anim3 = animation.FuncAnimation(
                self._figure_3, animate3, data_gen3, interval=5
                )

            self._figure_1_canvas.draw()
            self._figure_2_canvas.draw()
            self._figure_3_canvas.draw()

            self.btn_pausar.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.btn_iniciar.configure(text="Detener")
        else:
            self._ax1.lines = []  
            self._ax2.lines = []
            self._ax3.lines = []
            self.btn_pausar.configure(state=tk.DISABLED, text="  Pausa  ")
            self.btn_iniciar.configure(text="Iniciar")
            self._anim1 = self._anim2 = self._anim3 = None


    def pausar_animación(self):
        if self.btn_pausar["text"] == "  Pausa  ":
            self._anim1.event_source.stop()
            self._anim2.event_source.stop()
            self._anim3.event_source.stop()
            self.btn_pausar.configure(text="Continuar")

        else:
            self._anim1.event_source.start()
            self._anim2.event_source.start()
            self._anim3.event_source.start()
            self.btn_pausar.configure(text="  Pausa  ")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    VentanaSeñales(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me viene como anillo al dedo.